# Flattening JSON with no name properties

Tags: c#, json

```
{
    "build": 44396,
    "files": ["00005DC8F14C92FFA13E7FDF1C9C35E4684F8B7A", [
        ["file1.zip", 462485959, 462485959, 2, 0, 883, true, 266716, 1734, 992, 558, 0],
        ["file1.doc", 521042, 521042, 2, 0, 883, true, 266716, 1734, 992, 558, 0]
    ], "0001194B90612DFB5E8D363249719FB62E221430", [
        ["file2.iso", 501163544, 501163544, 2, 0, 956, true, 194777, 2573, 0, 0, 0]
    ], "0002B5245B0897BEA7D7F426E104B6D24FF368DE", [
        ["file3.mp4", 284564707, 284564707, 2, 0, 543, true, 205165, 1387, 853, 480, 0]
    ]]
}
```

Id like to flatten the above json to 
ID, fileName, fileSize
IE

```
00005DC8F14C92FFA13E7FDF1C9C35E4684F8B7A    file1.zip   462485959
00005DC8F14C92FFA13E7FDF1C9C35E4684F8B7A    file1.doc   521042
0001194B90612DFB5E8D363249719FB62E221430    file2.iso   501163544
0002B5245B0897BEA7D7F426E104B6D24FF368DE    file3.mp4   284564707
```

As you can see, most of the properties don't have names.
The file arrays also alternate the id with the file object.

I tried using classes, but got the error: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
{"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Rename.frmMain+jsonFiles' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. 
JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'files', line 1, position 25."}  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

```
public class jsonDetails
{
  public int build { get; set; }
  public object files { get; set; }
}

public class jsonFiles
{
  public string hash { get; set; }
  public string[][] files { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried using ExpandoObjects with no luck.

I've looked at linq to JSon.

Most of the examples I've seen online require property names.

How can we flatten the above JSON?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just go "schemaless" and use `JObject` directly, followed by a bit of LINQ to sort things out:

```
var jsonStr = @"{
    ""build"": 44396,
    ""files"": [""00005DC8F14C92FFA13E7FDF1C9C35E4684F8B7A"", [

        [""file1.zip"", 462485959, 462485959, 2, 0, 883, true, 266716, 1734, 992, 558, 0],
        [""file1.doc"", 521042, 521042, 2, 0, 883, true, 266716, 1734, 992, 558, 0]
    ], ""0001194B90612DFB5E8D363249719FB62E221430"", [

        [""file2.iso"", 501163544, 501163544, 2, 0, 956, true, 194777, 2573, 0, 0, 0]
    ], ""0002B5245B0897BEA7D7F426E104B6D24FF368DE"", [

        [""file3.mp4"", 284564707, 284564707, 2, 0, 543, true, 205165, 1387, 853, 480, 0]
    ]]
}";

var json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
var filesArr = json["files"];
var result = filesArr
    .Select((a, i) => new { a, i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .Select(g => new { id = g[0].a, vals = g[1].a })
    .SelectMany(x => x.vals.Select(v => new { x.id, val = v }))
    .Select(x => new { id = x.id.Value<string>(), 
                       filename = x.val[0].Value<string>(), 
                       size = x.val[1].Value<long>() });
```

Comment: Spender, that's excellent.
I didn't expect an answer so quickly.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @Don No probs. Was an interesting problem.